# How do I pass a variable to a view that is extended, and not called explicitly?

Tags: playframework

When a new app is created, two views are main.html and index.html. main is never explicitly rendered, it is extended as

`#{extends 'main.html' /}`

How do I pass a variable to a view (main.html), when its only extended from another view (index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is passed to the render method, it will be available as per normal. The entire view, including extends and includes are rendered by the Groovy template engine.

However, in the case of the `main.html` which is usually extended on every view, the best option is to always add it to the `renderArgs` map using the `@Before` annotation, as follows. This ensure that it is always available, and you Do Not Repeat Yourself (DRY).

```
@Before
private void setup() {
    renderArgs.put("somekey", "somevalue");
}
```

This way, you don't need to pass somekey into the render method on every render call.

Then, in your `main.html`, you can access `somekey` simply using the standard method of `$somekey`.

Answer (score 1):

Codemwnci gives the solution on how to pass variables to layout template from inside controller. Here is how to pass variables from your normal view to the layout view:

In your index.html, you can do something like:

```
#{set title:'My title'/}
```

And in your main.html, you can "get" the variables set in index.html:

```
<h1>#{get 'title'/}</h1>
```

If you are using [Rythm](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm) or [Japid](http://www.playframework.org/modules/japid) template engine, then you can pass variables to main.html directly in the `extends` statement

In Rythm template engine, suppose your main.html is:

```
@args String title
...
<h1>@title</h1>
...
```

You extend main template in index.html using the following statement:

```
@extends(main, "my title")
```